# NASM x64 read numbers to array and write out

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, system-calls

I have got a big problem with reading 10 numbers from keyboard to array and then writing them out.

`mov rcx, arr + qword [n]*8` - I don't know how to modify it properly, because actually it causes an error. 
Additionally how should I set `mov rdx, 1` when I want to read numbers like: 12 123 1234 not only digits?

I would be grateful for any kind of help.

```
global main

section .text

main:
mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
mov rdi, 0
_in:


mov rax, 3
mov rbx, 0
mov rcx, arr + rdi*8
mov rdx, 1
int 80h


mov rax, 3
mov rbx, 0
mov rcx, blank
mov rdx, 1
int 80h

inc qword [n]
cmp qword [n], 10
jz _next
jmp _in
inc rdi

_next:
mov qword [n], 0
mov rdi, 0
_out:
mov rax, 4
mov rbx, 1
mov rcx, arr + rdi*8
mov rdx, 1
int 80h

mov rax, 4
mov rbx, 1
mov rcx, nl
mov rdx, 1
int 80h

inc qword [n]
cmp qword [n], 10
jz _end
jmp _out
inc rdi
_end:

mov rax, 1
mov rbx, 0
ret

section .data

arr times 10 dq 0
blank db 0
n dq 0
nl db 10
```

Comment: You need to load `n` into a register if you want to index with it. The rest of your question is unclear.

Comment: sorry for unclearness but english is not my native language. I mean when I modify mov rdx, 2 I can read numbers from keyboard like 11, when I modify mov rdx, 3 I can read numbers like 111. I want to read all possible lengths of numbers.

Comment: Read them in a loop digit by digit?

Comment: Now I can read 10 numbers like that: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.

Comment: But I want to read them for example like that: 1 12 13 16 4 23 123 32 12 12046

Comment: @Jester I change my code, I made it simpler but it doesn't work.

Comment: So do it? Your `arr` is 10x8 bytes, so you can store into each element 8 ASCII characters (digits). Or you can directly convert the number while reading digits into numeric value, and store qword value.  Edit: in your new edit both `inc rdi` are unreachable.

Comment: @Ped7g What do you mean unreachable? I checked rdi incrementation and it works properly, but line: mov rcx, arr + rdi*8  shows an error: invalid operand type.

Comment: Is this `nasm`? If yes, use `[]` always when accessing memory content, ie `mov rcx,[arr+rdi*8]`. If you did want to calculate addres+rdi*8, use `lea rcx,[arr+rdi*8]`. Either way, without brackets there's no instruction accepting such source value/combination (immediate + rdi*8), that's possible only as memory addressing mode.  About unreachable: `jmp _in` 
`inc rdi`  (there's unconditional jump right ahead of `inc rdi`).

Comment: @Ped7g Yes, it's NASM, but when I use [ ] then it doesn't print results.

Comment: for sys_read/sys_write you need address of buffer, so `lea rcx,[]`. `lea` is like `mov` from memory, but it stops after calculating target address, and instead of contacting memory chip to load value from calculated address, it will store the address into destination. So it's one of the exceptions, where you should use `[]` brackets, but it actually doesn't contact the memory chip. I'm not sure if it is the *only* such exception, but I can't recall any other, everything else with brackets is working with memory content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About input and data structures.

Keep reading per char (`rdx=1`), in a loop. Input chars will be for example `'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 10`, the character `10` is new line (maybe check also for other whitespace chars like `13, 9, 32` too, or even flip the test, any char out of `'0'..'9'` range is end of number).

While reading digits, decide if you want to store them as strings, or as numbers.

If strings, then write every new digit into memory at address arr+n*8+input_char_index, put probably zero value as terminator after the number (your current array can hold at most 7 character long strings + zero for each "n"), or store string length into separate array, or as first byte of element, and make first char go at +1 offset after the length byte, etc... (you can design your data structure as you wish). To display such string just load it's address `lea rcx,[arr+n*8]` and calculate it's length with `strlen` (it reads+counts char by char until `0` is found), or load the length if you have it stored somewhere, and sys_write it.

If you want to store numbers, set some spare register as zero ahead of input (for example `rdi`), then for every digit read do `add rdi,rdi` `lea rdi,[rdi+rdi*4]` => that's `rdi *= 10`, then convert the input character from ASCII digit to 64b 0-9 value, and add it to `rdi` ... loop until non-digit or newline is read (but 64b unsigned number will overflow for 19+ digits input). After end of input store the value into `arr`, now `arr` will contain numerical QWORD values.

To output them, you have to do the conversion in opposite direction, from numerical value into some memory buffer, producing digit by digit ASCII characters (have big enough buffer, again 20+ chars is safe for 64b value). After you have your number stored in memory as ASCII string + know it's length, you can SYS_WRITE it to stdout.

You may also consider to follow some more tutorials first and re-read some theory about common data structures/etc, memory, string encodings, registers, x86 addressing modes, .... before writing your own code (as it feels to me that you are guessing a bit too much, how things work).

Comment: Thank you very much, you helpt me a lot in better understanding it. Now my program works perfectly.